# Наследование классов и метод toString() в Kotlin

Tags: классы, kotlin, наследование

В моём проекте есть два класса: родительский - `ProductRecord` и дочерний data class - `Product`. В иерархии `Product` наследует поле `name`, далее я привожу дочерний к родительскому и получаю интересную ситуацию:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val prodRec = ProductRecord("Milk", 12)
    val prod = Product("Egg", 23, 647)
    
    val test: ProductRecord = prod

    println(test.toString())
    // Unresolved reference: money
    // println("Наименование=${test.name} Количество=${test.number} Стоимость=${test.money}")
}
```

Вывод:

```
Имя=Egg, Количество=23, Стоимость=647
```

Т.е. доступа к свойству `money` я больше не имею, но метод `toString()` содержит ссылку на дочерний класс и выводит мне это поле.
Я читал, что классы данных и наследование не самые совместимые вещи, но хотелось бы иметь возможность приведения типа к родительскому с родительской реализацией `toString()`.

P.s. переписал класс данных на обычный и переопределил `toString()`, проблема осталась та же самая. Пожалуйста, подскажите что я понимаю не так и как вместе со свойством `money` использовать реализацию метода `toString()` из родительского класса.

Answer (score 0):

Ситуация, которую я описал выше - это не каст, а присвоение ссылки экземпляра родителю, т.е. объект остаётся тот же самый. Для каста типов в Kotlin можно написать свою функцию расширения toProductRecord().